# Flex / Flash Builder SVN: what files and folders should not be checked into subversion?

Tags: apache-flex, svn, flexbuilder, flash-builder, subclipse

Background: Trying to set up my dev. environment in new job. Have subversion installed ok in Flash Builder 4, and checked out the project folders I will be working on. Work to date was developed in FB3, I'm going to be using FB4.

The folders/files that get imported to the project also include .flexProperties, .actionScriptProperties, .project, html-template etc (basically everything).

I would have thought that just the src, libs, lib-rsl etc should be part of the svn?

**UPDATE:** 
[Here is a good link](http://www.aliaspooryorik.com/blog/index.cfm/e/posts.details/post/203) to setup details for sharing svn flex projects using 2 folders, one of which has the checkout code, the other of which has folders linked to the first (but without the project/setup files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the the development group. If everyone is provided the exact same set of tools in the exact same environments it can be ok to include the IDE project files. But if there is any chance that anyone is going to use a different environment (this includes a rolling upgrade of tools) then it is a bad idea. I recommend against putting these files in source control.